# Arrow Function lose Strong typing information Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Why is the last line not showing an error when I use Fat Arrow function ?

```
Future<String> foo() async {
  return "foo";
}

void bar() {
  return foo(); // A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be returned from the function 'bar' because it has a return type of 'void'
}

void baz () => foo(); // no compiler error ? Why ?
```

Is this intentional ? If so, how to make Dart compiler report this error as it may lead to bugs . Use case: For example, `foo` is a Future, it should be awaited otherwise it will lead to bad state in my app.

This bug is used in the Go Router package by Flutter.dev  `void pushReplacement(String location, {Object? extra}) => GoRouter.of(this).pushReplacement(location, extra: extra);`

Which makes me think this might not be a bug but intentional. But why ?

Comment: You can see the related issue about that extension methods from go_router [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/124686)